# Is there a direct way to know to which view I am going in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an interval running that I want to leave active if the user goes to a specific view.

Is there a way to check this in `$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave')` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$stateChangeStart` event, which is triggered when users navigate to another state and gives you the next state, so you can find the view you are going to. Also, you can check the current state if it's a matter or stop the state navigation by stopping the event default (i.e. `event.preventDefault();`). So then, you can enable yout `$interval` within the event handler or disable as well.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
            function (event, nextState, nextParams, currentState, currentParams) {
   // use the nextState to handle this
   // and use event.proventDefault() to stop the state change
});
```

Comment: I'm using the `$interval` to fetch GPS info, not for the state change. thanks!

Comment: @distante got it, so you can enable this `$interval` inside the `'$stateChangeStart'` handler.

Comment: Also just for notice, I used `$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` because just needed to check that change in one specific view

Comment: That makes no significant difference, because the `$stateChangeStart` is broadcasted from `$rootScope` which will make the event be propagated to all child scopes. It's up to you.

Comment: I just mean my interval starts in one specific view, so just need to check it when I go out of that view. So no need (for me) to use it on `$rootScope` :)